# How to statistically test an increase?

Tags: statistical-significance, networks

I have two temporal networks in which I report their number of nodes and the average degree in different time intervals:

| time | Nodes_Network_1 | Nodes_Network_2 | Average_degree_Network_1 | Average_degree_Network_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| time_1 | 150 | 57 | 3.2 | 2.8 |
| time_2 | 477 | 102 | 3.7 | 3.2 |
| time_3 | 949 | 170 | 5.9 | 3.4 |
| time_4 | 1137 | 314 | 6.7 | 4.8 |
| time_5 | 1167 | 263 | 8.9 | 5.9 |

I want show that:

While the Average_degree increases over time for both networks, I'm mainly interested in testing the last time interval (from time_4 to time_5) and
I'd like to be able to say "The increase in Average_degree_Net_1 (from 6.7 to 8.9) is statistically higher than than for Average_degree_Net_2 (from 4.8 to 5.9)".

what statistical test can be used here?

Comment: [One-sided t-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/342074), if you must.

Comment: How do we know whether it's a t-test or a Wilcoxon test?

Comment: But the sample is increasing over time, and I'm mainly interested in comparing the values of the last time interval. I'm not sure whether the required assumptions for a t-test are met here.