# Misinterpretation of statistics: falsely accused

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, references

Not sure if it is on topic, but I use to help a friend of mine in a basic statistics course. Current topic is hypothesis testing and confidence intervals. I remember that I saw a good example that might illustrate the concepts, however I cannot find it on the Internet. It is about a judge who incorrectly interpreted statistics in his judgment and falsely accused a person. Unfortunately, this is all information that I remember. Many thanks.

Comment: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2008-2009/TianyiZheng/Bayes.html?

Comment: @ChristophHanck no, unfortunately not that one, but thanks for sharing the link!

Comment: Here are a lot of very good answers on hypothesis testing in case you cannot find the reference you are after https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185023/why-is-the-null-hypothesis-often-sought-to-be-rejected/185054#185054